# rails date input only accepts days 1 to 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, date, date-format

My Rails form has:

```
f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size: 10
```

and this works fine for the first 12 days of months.
But for days 13-31 no date is saved and any existing one is wiped out.

I tried adding:

```
:value => @link.content_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

as in

```
= f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size: 10#, :value => @link.content    _date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

but it didn't help.

```
Params hash example:

Parameters: {
"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"90RFyJDhQYeqMsUgJXSSWT/1Mrc3Mz27+cVbMg/dEfY=", 
"link"=>{"url_address"=>"http://www.test.com", 
"alt_text"=>"t22", 
"version_number"=>"", 
"group_id"=>"34", 
"content_date"=>"11/30/2014"}, 
"commit"=>"Save", 
"id"=>"360"}
```

I also tried adding

```
Default format for displaying dates and times
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

to `config/initializers/time_format.rb`, but this just makes the date cycle between formats when saved, e.g. does 04/02/2012, then shows 02/04/2012, then shows 04/02/2012, etc.

Setting them to

```
Default format for displaying dates and times
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

doesn't do that but still only works for the first 12 days of the month.
The attached js date picker is showing the correct date, e.g. 02/12 is February 12th.

Controller:

```
  def update
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update_attributes(params[:link])
        flash[:notice] = 'Link was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@link.group) }
      else
        @groups = Group.find(:all)
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Your best bet is to always communicate with the server in ISO 8601 formats (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD). Your date picker can display whatever format it wants but it should send YYYY-MM-DD to the server.

Comment: Thanks mu (much snow this year?).  How do I do that?

Comment: Depends on the date picker, the jQuery-UI one at least has [`altField` and `altFormat` options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField). Lots of snow in February thanks.

Comment: +1 Hmmm, was about to go there but then found the 'american_date' gem fixed both this and a display on the show page, so going with date.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `gem 'american_date'` to your gemfile.  I had to do that in a recent project.

Comment: Perfect and even fixed the display on the show page so it matches everywhere.  Nice fix.